# s3 presigned url doesn't work outside my network

Tags: amazon-s3

I user sdk v.3 to store & retrieve files from s3. I've generated presigned url & it works fine from my network. But I can't access the url from other network.
here's my code

```
    $sharedConfig = [
    'version'     => 'latest',
        'region'      => 'eu-west-1',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => '...',
            'secret' => '...'
        ]
];

$sdk = new Aws\Sdk($sharedConfig);

$s3Client = $sdk->createS3();

$object = [
    'Bucket'    => 'test.bucket',
    'Key'       => 'icon.png'
];

$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject',$object);
$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+5 minutes');
```

Is there any way to make the url completely public for 5 minutes without changing the bucket ACL? btw, I am getting following error while trying to access the presigned url from other network.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>A793BD3D8DF125E5</RequestId>
<HostId>
1nV37sDXfKGEkHuiDGY9I8TNZllIL8jDQabC4vlpuAtSDllOay3qGglf9Y/EW6wFILnfAszG/YM=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: The pre-signed URL is unrelated to the bucket ACL and it should work from anywhere on the Internet (as long as there is no DENY policy active on the object). How did you test the URL from "other network"? Are you saying that *exactly the same pre-signed URL* worked from one location on the internet and not another, both within the 5-minute period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presigned Url are generated for public access. but my bucket allows access only from a specific IP. Thats why I was unable to access the url from any other network.

I served my purpose by making another download service on my server(which is white listed) and for download the file to the requester.